# can´t save excel in pandas

Tags: excel, pandas

> When i try to save a file xlsx make an error. The option to save in csv not be possible. Tried to save without "with" but i got another error:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import xlwt


with pd.ExcelWriter('base.xlsx') as writer:
    df_por_presentacion.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='base')
```

> Error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/Python/Pandas/lisdj.py", line 65, in <module>
    df_por_presentacion.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='base')
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 777, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 781, in close
    return self.save()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 43, in save
    return self.book.save(self.path)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 392, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 293, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 75, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 215, in _write_worksheets
    self.write_worksheet(ws)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 200, in write_worksheet
    writer.write()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 359, in write
    self.write_rows()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 125, in write_rows
    self.write_row(xf, row, row_idx)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 147, in write_row
    write_cell(xf, self.ws, cell, cell.has_style)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\_writer.py", line 45, in etree_write_cell
    el = Element("c", attributes)
MemoryError
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 32, in _openpyxl_shutdown
    os.remove(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] 
The process does not have access to the file because it is being used by another process: The process does not have access to the file because it is being used by another process:'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\openpyxl.uqzfxnjq'
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

> I try to use "with" because will be a better way but i have an error.
> I try reboot the computer, but still happen
> How i fix it?

Comment: Based on the error, base.xlsx is already open. Open task manager and see if Excel is running.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error code was in Pycharm.
I try in Spyder (the same code!!!) and work fine. The file was created!!!